# Many ways to do the same thing .. can performance testing help me decide?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, performance

All what I know about performance testing is what it's name suggests!

But I have some problems specially with the database querying techniques and how will it affect my application's performance at normal times and at stress!

So can performance tests calculates for me a certain page's performance ?
Can I do that on the development machine (my own pc/local host) ?
Or I have to test it on the hosting server ? do I have to own a server or shared hosting is okay ?
what are the available books/articles ? and the good free tools to use ?

I know I asked a lot of questions but they will actually all adds up to help anyone that is having the same spins in my head when trying to decide which technique to use and can't get a definite opinion from the experienced ones!

Thanks in advance for your time and effort =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you know you have problems with your db architecture, then it sounds like you don't really need to do load testing at this time, you'd be better served figuring out what your db issues are.

As for the overall, "how can I load test, and what are some good directions to go?" It depends on a couple of things.  First, you *could* test in your dev environment, though unless its the same setup as the production environment (server setup / cpu memory / ect.), then it is only going to be an estimate.  In general I prefer to use a staging / test environment that mimics the production environment as closely as possible.

If you think you're going to have an application with high usage you'll want to know what your performance is period, whether dedicated or shared hosting.  I will say, however, that if you are expecting a high traffic site / application, you'll probably have a number of reasons to have a dedicated hosting environment (or a cloud based solution).

There are some decent free tools available, specifically there is http://jmeter.apache.org/ which can plug into a bunch of stuff, the catch is that, while the gui interface is better than years ago, its not as good as some of the commercial options available.

You'll ultimately run into an issue where you can only bang on something so much from a single client computer, even with one of these packages, and you'll need to start distributing that load.  That is where the commercial packages start to really provide some good benefits.

For C# specifically, and .Net projects in general, Visual Studio (depedning on your version) should have something like Test Projects, which you can read more about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182605(v=vs.80).aspx  That may be closer, specifically, to what you were asking in the first place.

Comment: First of all, I'll start with a shared hosting and if the website got the huge traffic I was aiming for then I'll move to a dedicated server .. but I still need to test my application to see if it's ready to scale ! will I be able to do that on a shared account ?
will Jmeter work with asp.net ?

Comment: Jmeter just makes requests to your web server and logs information about the response.  So yes, it doesn't matter what you wrote in, it will be able to tell you information about the responses back from your web server.

Comment: +1 Great .. any tools for stress load tests ? .. about the commercial and the free packages, I didn't understand if I can stress/load test my application using free packages ?

Comment: You can test with JMeter, it has options to set it to create multiple connections, and do it concurrently, ect.  You can plan with the options to get what you want.  But to truly loadtest you'd need to have more than one computer involved in the testing.  I can't speak to the .Net Test Projects.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic without access to the server is:

```
Console.write("Starting in " + DateTime.Now;)
//code
Console.write("Ending in " + DateTime.Now;)
```

Then you can measure what consult takes more time.
But you need to test with more scenarios, an approach can be better that other in certain cases, but vice-versa in others.

Comment: hmm, is this is what performance testing is based on or this is just a simple idea to measure the execution of a page? and the worst flaw of this approach is that you'll never be able to simulate a load stress test!

Comment: Its the more simple approach. There are too: stress testing, corner case testing, black box, white box, [memory,disc] profiling. Also the testing can be automated with unit tests or tools like watir or autoIt. There are more people with an academic background that know more, im just an empiric QA Software Engineer;).

Comment: +1 for the simple method I might use until I find and learn a good tool to let me test my application in a more professional way .. and if you know anything about those tests articles/books that would be great if you could reference them in here!

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky subject, and you will need more than just Stack Overflow to work through this - though I'm not aware of any books or web sites. This is just my experience talking...

In general, you want to know 2 things:

- how many visitors can my site handle?
- what do I need to do to increase that number?

You usually need to manage these concurrently.

My approach is to include performance testing into the development lifecycle, by creating a test environment (a dev machine is usually okay) on which I can control all the variables.

I use JMeter to run performance tests mimicking the common user journeys, and establish the number of users where the system starts to exceed maximum allowed response times (I typically use 1 second as the limit). Once I know where that point is, I will use analysis tools to understand what is causing the system to exceed its response time - is it the database? Should I introduce caching? Tools like [PAL](http://pal.codeplex.com/) make this easy; at a more detailed level, you should use profilers (Redgate do a great one).

I run this process for an afternoon, once every two weeks, so there's no nasty surprise at the end of the project. By doing this, I have a high degree of confidence in my application's performance, and I know what to expect on "production" hardware.

On production, it's much harder to get accesso to the data which allows you to analyze a bottleneck - and once the site is live, it's usually harder to get permission to run performance tests which can bring the site down. On anything other than a start-up site, the infrastructure requirements mean it's usually too expensive to have a test environment that reflects live.

Therefore, I usually don't run a performance test on production which drives the app to the breaking point - but I do run "smoke tests", and collect log files which allow the PAL reports to be generated. The smoke test pushes the environment to a level which I expect to be around 50% of the breaking point - so if I think we've got a capacity of 100 concurrent users, the smoke test will go to 50 concurrent users.